# SELECT specific columns from EXEC stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, stored-procedures

I am having an issue trying to `SELECT` specific columns from an `EXEC` statement on a stored procedure. I am trying to find the `COUNT(*)` that the stored procedure returns which I am successfully doing with :

```
INSERT INTO #temp
EXEC dbo.my_sp
SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp)
DELETE FROM #temp
```

However, this only works if the columns returned match specifically with the table columns and since I am trying to find the count of many different stored procedures (each of which return different columns), I cannot use this method without creating a new table for each stored procedure.

Is there a way I can `SELECT` specific columns from the `EXEC dbo.my_sp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would @@ROWCOUNT work for you?

```
if OBJECT_ID('SomeProc') is null
    exec ('create procedure dbo.SomeProc as select 1 as SomeValue union all select 2 as SomeValue;')

exec dbo.SomeProc

Select @@ROWCOUNT as RowsAffected
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This works for me. But now each `exec` call is actually returning the data, which is wasn't before. I'm using 

`EXEC dbo.my_sp1`
`SET @value1= (SELECT @@ROWCOUNT)`
`EXEC dbo.my_sp2`
`SET @value2 = (SELECT @@ROWCOUNT)`
`SELECT @value1, @value2`

I only want the two values, not the values from the `exec`

Comment: What's the end result of the stored procedure? Are you using the returned data in something?

Comment: It returns rows of data that I need for other purposes. And for now, I want to count how many rows are returned

Comment: Are you consuming it in another stored procedure or .net or something? With .net you could just get the last dataset returned. You would probably need to restructure if you are consuming in another stored proc

Comment: I understand now, I am not consuming it in another stored procedure. I was consuming it earlier (from original question) by storing it into a temp table, but now I just want to select the row count. Is there a simple way to consume the data set so it does not show up in the returned list so that I only get the count values?

Comment: Depending on what you're using this stored procedure for you could use output parameters or you could refactor the stored procedures to return a count or something. I'm not sure I have a good answer for you otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Create a loopback linked server to the local instance, making sure that data access is enabled. Let's say you have a local named instance called `YourServer\SQL2008`:

```
USE [master];
GO
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
  @server     = N'LoopbackLocal', 
  @srvproduct = N'',
  @provider   = N'SQLNCLI', 
  @datasrc    = N'.\SQL2008', 
  @catalog    = N'tempdb';
GO

EXEC sp_serveroption 
  @server   = N'LoopbackLocal', 
  @optname  = N'collation compatible', 
  @optvalue = N'true';
GO

EXEC sp_serveroption 
  @server   = N'LoopbackLocal', 
  @optname  = N'data access', 
  @optvalue = N'true';
GO

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
  @rmtsrvname = N'LoopbackLocal', 
  @locallogin = NULL , 
  @useself    = N'True';
GO
-- you may need to configure other security here
```

Then you can use `OPENQUERY` to run a stored procedure as if it were an ad hoc query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM OPENQUERY
  (
    LoopbackLocal, 
    'EXEC dbo.my_sp'
  ) AS y;
```

Now, if `dbo.my_sp` dumps information into a #temp table first, you're going to have issues, since it is no longer a block of code that `OPENQUERY` can process. For example, if you try to execute `sp_who2` this way, at least in SQL Server 2012, you will get an error from `sp_describe_first_result_set` which `OPENQUERY` has been altered to use (so maybe this works for you now, I don't have 2008 to test, but it will be an issue someday):

> Msg 11526, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1
>   
> The metadata could not be determined because ... uses a temp table.

If you're going to be doing this a lot, however, why not make specialized stored procedures (or add options to these ones) such that only a count is returned?

Comment: I do see this working, however I do not have permissions to perform this task (I'm not working from home, so it's something I unfortunately cannot fix/change). Also I won't be performing the task a lot, so I'd like to keep the process in one simple stored procedure if possible.

Comment: Is there any way to make this work when the procedure uses a temp table? SQL 2012 gives an error about sp_describe_first_result_set failing with procs using temp table storage. Edit: nevermind, just saw your edit!

Comment: @KevinDahl I don't think so, it seems `OPENQUERY` has been changed to use those new procedures internally, and this is a known limitation with them (`OPENROWSET()` fails the same way).